# asp.net core 2.1 on arch linux does not run

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, configuration, .net-core, archlinux

I have installed the latest version of the .net core using pacman on an Arch Linux:

```
sudo pacman -S dotnet-sdk
```

Running `dotnet --info` shows the correct version:

```
Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.0
  Commit:  caa7b7e2ba

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.0 [/opt/dotnet/sdk]
  2.1.300 [/opt/dotnet/sdk]
```

I can run console applications, but when I run `dotnet run` in an ASP.NET Core directory return this error:

> It was not possible to find any compatible framework version The
>   specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.0' was
>   not found.

Why though versions seem to match, it doesn't run?

**More details:**

`ls /opt/dotnet/sdk/` returns:

```
2.1.300  NuGetFallbackFolder
```

Contents of the `.csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is old, but in case someone's trying to get .NET 5 to run on Arch, this can give you another solution.

If you build, publish and run the project specifying the platform runtime, `dotnet` will build a self-contained application, with all necessary platform specific dependencies.

You can do that with the `--runtime`/`-r` flag.

Examples for Arch:

```
dotnet build -r linux-x64
```

```
dotnet run -r linux-x64
```

```
dotnet publish -r linux-x64
```

Refer to Microsoft docs for the available runtime identifiers:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog

---

Edit:

I've also had less problems with paths using the AUR package instead of Snap's:

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/dotnet-sdk-bin/

---

Edit 2:

After installing AUR's `aspnet-runtime-bin` package, all errors about `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` not being found disappeared, without using the `--runtime` flag:

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/aspnet-runtime-bin

---

Answer (score 2):

.NET Core is not currently supported on Arch, so there's no guarantees that it will work at all. Currently the following distros are supported on 64-bit:

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7, 6
- CentOS 7
- Oracle Linux 7
- Fedora 27
- Debian 9, 8.7 or later versions
- Ubuntu 18.04, 17.10, 16.04, 14.04
- Linux Mint 18, 17
- openSUSE 42.3 or later versions
- SUSE Enterprise Linux (SLES) 12 Service Pack 2 or later
- Alpine Linux 3.7 or later versions

See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x) for more info.

You can see these issues related to Arch in the dotnet repos:

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/4409

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/19447

https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/3845

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the issue you have mentioned seems to address a number of other minor (less major!) problems of the dotnet core on Linux arch. Though Microsoft does not officially support it, the AUR package exists and seems it works (I guess).

Comment: It's probably possible to hack around and get it to work, but your question implies that .NET Core should be able to run on Arch Linux whereas in actuality, it is not expected to run yet, so I think my answer is correct. I've added extra issues above to help as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a proper solution for your problem but maybe a workaround. I am using elementary os and .net core 2.1 works just fine, but I noticed that my path to the metapackages is different from yours:

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.300
 Commit:    adab45bf0c

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     elementary
 OS Version:  0.4.1
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         linux-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.0
  Commit:  caa7b7e2ba

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.0.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
  2.1.300 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

You could try to copy the metapackages from your installation folder `/opt/dotnet/shared` to `/usr/share/dotnet/shared`

This guy over here has a similar problem using Fedora: https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/4022

Comment: I'll try your workaround and update my comment by the next week. Thanks :-)

Comment: I did it by creating a symlink, getting the same error, thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

@tura08 answer is wrong, because *.NET Core* should work on *Arch Linux* like on every other Linux system.

I was experiencing same issue so I just reported it https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/4216 and it seems *dotnet-sdk* package is missing *aspnetcore-runtime-2.1* dependency. I wrote email to maintainer, so I hope he will fix package soon.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue trying to get global tools installed. Creating a symlink worked for me:

```
ln -s /opt/dotnet/ /usr/share/dotnet
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have already tried it, and it results in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading all the packages solved the problem:

```
pacman -Syu
```

It includes the `dotnet-sdk` package 2.1.300-2 updated on 2018-06-12 11:24 UTC:
https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/dotnet-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

Just install these:

```
sudo pacman -S dotnet-sdk aspnet-runtime
```